# Drawing a bitmap to canvas and calling .setImageBitmap() causes image to be cropped

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-bitmap

I'm simply drawing a bitmap from my drawable folder onto the canvas and setting that bitmap into an `ImageView`. It works perfectly fine on my Emulator, but on my real device why is it being cropped? It makes no sense. The code is exactly the same

```
Drawable backgroundDrawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.landscape);

 try {
            Bitmap backgroundBitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) backgroundDrawable).getBitmap();
           
            int positionLeft = 0;
            int positionTop = 0;
            Bitmap mainBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
                    backgroundBitmap.getWidth(),
                    backgroundBitmap.getHeight(),
                    Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888
            );
            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(mainBitmap);
            canvas.drawBitmap(backgroundBitmap, positionLeft, positionTop, null);   
            drawingPad.setImageBitmap(mainBitmap);
            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "onClickCreateImg: Error: ", e);
        }
```

On my emulator (Pixel 2) there is no issue:

[image]

But on my real device (Pixel 4a) the image is being automatically cropped? Why does this happen

[image]

I dont think it has anything to do with the layout, but here it is.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/parentLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_create_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:text="Create image"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/drawingPad"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btn_create_image"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:paddingBottom="32dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingTop="32dp"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Instead of using `.setImageBitmap(mainBitmap)`
I used the Glide library instead

```
Glide.with(NewsFragment.this)
                   .load(mainBitmap)
                   .apply(RequestOptions.centerInsideTransform())
                   .into(drawingPad);
```

But this weird unexpected cropping issue is still happening only on my real device.

Tested on a 3rd device Emulator (Nexus 5X) doesn't get cropped either.

[image]

**___________________________________________________**

Tested on a 4th Real Device (Pixel 3XL) and it also gets cropped.

Still can't figure out why this is happening...

Comment: have tried adding ```android:scaleType="fitCenter"``` to the imageview's xml, but still being cropped only on real devices (not emulators)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your issue is due to an unspecified "density" on the canvas and/or bitmap.  You can force both canvas and bitmap to a common density by adding the following code:

```
canvas.setDensity(DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_MEDIUM);
mainBitmap.setDensity(DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_MEDIUM);
```

though I'm uncertain if you have density specific versions of your `R.drawable.landscape` asset in your resource folders.

The above suggestion should get you close.

Lastly (I suspect you know this and have good reason for wanting to use Canvas) you could just do this:

```
Drawable backgroundDrawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.landscape);
drawingPad.setImageDrawable(backgroundDrawable);
```

or this:

```
drawablePad.setImageResource(R.drawable.landscape);
```